# Documenting the no-args call of a command line program

Tags: technical-writing, software-documentation

I am writing the built-in help for a command line program. The exact name is irrelevant, so let's use `foo` as a placeholder.

This utility can be called with some arguments (like `foo -v`) or without any arguments at all (just `foo`).

I'm struggling with describing the no-argument call in the built-in help. (There's a common practice that the `-h` or `--help` argument is used to print that help on the screen.)
A common output of `-h` command looks like this:

```
$ foo -h
foo [OPTIONS...]

Do FOO in the most awesome way possible

  -h --help           Show this help
  -v --version        Show package version
```

Note the pattern for explaining arguments:

```
  (short) (long)      Explanation
```

The no-argument call doesn't fit in this pattern.
All these variants look quite unnatural:

```
  foo                 Do the FOO
                      Do the FOO
  (no arguments)      Do the FOO
```

In search for examples I've looked at several utilities that have valid no-argument calls (e.g. `sh`, `bash` and other shells, `systemctl`), but none of them describe that in the `-h` output.

The question: what is the proper way of documenting the no-arguments call in the built-in help?

- Should I write something in the place of `(no arguments)` above?
- Or should I explain that in a different place (where)?

Comment: @NeilFein Was planning to do so the minute I made the comment. Here:http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1271/do-the-on-topic-rules-fit-non-fiction-particularly-technical-writing

Comment: @NickVolynkin, welcome to Writers and thank you for bringing your question here.  I hope you'll continue to ask tech-writing questions here.  Check out the tag, too; we have a bunch of other questions you might be interested in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arguments modify the behavior of a program. Running it without arguments means you get is default, unmodified behavior. So the help should describe the default unmodified behavior first, in the body of the description.

```
$ foo -h
foo [OPTIONS...]

Foo does X. For example:

   foo

X happens.

To make foo do Y, use the -y option. For example:

   foo -y

X happens with a shot of Y.


Arguments:

  -h --help           Show this help
  -v --version        Show package version
  -y                  Make Y happen
```

Comment: I salute you, sir, for not only making sense of that question but actually coming up with a comprehensible, usable answer.

Comment: Note that this is *why* those other command docs didn't have a "no-args" line where you were looking.

Comment: I do it almost the same. I might say foo with no arguments does ... Another way to address this is to add a defaults to section for optional arguments which gives more details of what foo does without a separate section for it.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, your first line takes care of that:

```
Do FOO in the most awesome way possible
```

Square braces for `[OPTIONS]` imply all options are optional.

If arguments modify the behavior, give the default behavior in absence of an argument.

```
-f filename     Perform FOO on file given, instead of standard input.
```

If parameters were not optional, you put them in `<>`.

```
foo [OPTIONS] <URL>

    Process FOO of the URL in the most awesome way possible.
```

In this case, if this use is standard, but you may allow *exceptional* use without the URL, you detail this in the last line, apart from the options:

```
Called without arguments, foo displays this help, same as -h.
```

Comment: `Square braces for [OPTIONS] imply all options are optional` – yes, that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: Lots of CLI utilities really display help when called without arguments or with wrong arguments. But in my case the no-args call is not exceptional or erroneous.

Comment: Yes, this.  Here's an [example](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) of a command with default behavior and a bunch of options.

Comment: @MonicaCellio thanks for the example, it is just perfect. Shame on me for not thinking about `ls`. :)

Comment: Re-read this answer just now. Thanks for pointing at the difference between standard and exceptional use. It appears quite important.

Answer (score 3):

I must misunderstand your question, but it seems to me that the function call without argument is already explained in the function description:

[image]

Comment: The example was oversimplified and real CLI utilities usually have more text before the args table. And what I meant was the description of the overall functionality, related to any of the arguments below. But you're right. That is exactly the place where it is explained, or at least should be explained.